# View webpage on button click on Hero Card in Microsoft Teams

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

I have a message extension running in MS Teams.

The search list displays the `Hero Card`.

On selecting one of them it displays something like below in the chat.

[image]

Part of code that displays the button:

```
...

heroCard.content.buttons = [{
   type: 'invoke',
   title: 'Open Attachment',
   value: {
    type: "task/fetch",
    messageId: "12345",
   }
}];
```

---

I am looking to run my angular app on clicking `Open Attachment` which displays the documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the way to proceed using [Microsoft Docs: Use task modules from bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots?tabs=nodejs)

**First I need to tweak the hero card button to pass my data.**

```
...

heroCard.content.buttons = [{
   type: 'invoke',
   title: 'Open Attachment',
   value: {
     type: "task/fetch",
     messageId: "12345",
     data: attachments
   }
}];
```

**The second thing is to handle the fetch request:**

```
async handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch(context, action) {

   var attachments = action.data.data

   return {
     task: {
       type: 'continue',
       value: {
         height: 400,
         width: 400,
         title: 'View Documents',
         url: `https://example.io?data=${attachments}`
       }
     }
  };
}
```

**Note: the URL must be in the valid domain of the manifest - otherwise you'll see the blank page.**

---

**The below is the final output:**

[image]