# Is there a way to embed iframe to Teams chat/conversation?

Tags: excel, forms, iframe, microsoft-teams

I have an iframe from ms forms, and want to get the 'survey' to work in teams chat.
(Basically I need to get the results in an Excel and not share the results with anyone)

The code is in this format:

`<iframe width="640px" height= "480px" src= "https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?xxxxxxxxxxx=true" frameborder= "0" marginwidth= "0" marginheight= "0" style= "border: none; max-width:100%; max-height:100vh" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen> </iframe>`

Comment: You can open the task module from adaptivecard/herocard to render a custom webpage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557353/view-webpage-on-button-click-on-hero-card-in-microsoft-teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to achieve what you are looking for using Task module. Please use [Task module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules) to display the iFrame. This Task module can be launched in various ways and one way is via a button in an Adaptive Card.